# Delete using group by with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-delete

I want to delete all the rows which are returned by this query.

```sql
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM myTable GROUP BY col1, col2, col3 HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

I tried this, but it gives me a syntax error.

```sql
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE col1, col2, col3 IN ( 
                       SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM   ( 
                              SELECT   col1, col2, col3 FROM myTable 
                              GROUP BY col1, col2, col3 HAVING count(*) > 1 ) 
                            t );
```

Comment: Do not use WHERE IN, use your SELECT as subquery joined to the table copy which the rows will be deleted from.

Comment: Error message and query text does not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an INNER JOIN with your table

```
DELETE t1 FROM myTable t1
        INNER JOIN ( 
                       SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM   ( 
                              SELECT   col1, col2, col3 FROM myTable 
                              GROUP BY col1, col2, col3 HAVING count(*) > 1 ) 
                            t )
    t2 ON t2.rcol1 = t1.rcol1 AND t2.col2 = t1.col AND t2.col3 = t1.col3;
```

But you you **should test** it on a test database, because i don't think that your select identifies the right rows, better would be to have a UNIQUE column, that would identify the correct rows, because this would delete all rows

Comment: I am checking for duplicate rows. Lets say there are 32 duplicates (therefore 64 rows in total). This query will delete all 64. How can I delete only 32 rows? Thanks.

Comment: you mus add a row_number and only delete row_number  > 1 and you need still a unque identifier or you have to add the rownumber also to the source table